# More button is not visible in tabbbaritem

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using the following code to customize tabbar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

// The following line centres the UITabBarItem. 
        [UITabBarItem appearance].titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(20, -20);
//the following line make the tabbaritem button with tag 4 to appear as more button
        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:4];
}
```

But the problem is that, the more button is not being shown for the tabbaritem with tag 4. I have five tabs and I want to show more button after three tabs. Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to manually create a **"More..."** button. 
Simply add all of the View Controllers that you need to the Tab Bar Controller and it will handle the rest.

If you want to create then one of the solution is,

You could make your own `More` tab and then have it display a `navigation controller` and `table view` with the other options.

**do it like following way:**

You can set the last bar button as a "More" button even when there are only 4 tabs. The initialization code for that tab bar item would be:

```
self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:0];
```

I hope this will work perfectly..:)